# Is it possible to push values to Kafka asynchronously using cats.effect.IO and FS2 Streams while returning an HTTP response immediately?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, scala-cats, fs2, doobie

The problem that I'm trying to solve can be described as follows:

1. A k8s scheduler calls each Monday morning an HTTP endpoint of my Finagle/Finch application
2. The HTTP endpoint will handle the request and returns an `IO[Int]` (immediately)
3. Before generating the HTTP response the execution of another function should be started, so it would run asynchronously
4. The async process should consume a data stream coming from a Postgres RDB produced using Doobie
5. That stream should be manipulated in constant memory and the data should be pushed into a Kafka topic

```scala
  val myHTTPEndpoint: Endpoint[IO, Int] =
    get("k8s-trigger") { () =>
      keyService
        .processKeys(LocalDateTime.now)
        .map(Ok)
    }
```

```scala
class KeyService {
  def processKeys(endDateTime: LocalDateTime): IO[Int] =
    for {
      numberOfKeys <- reportCardRepository.countReportCardKeys(endDateTime) // Doobie Repo
      _ <- IO.shift *> enqueueKeys(endDateTime, numberOfKeys, keysAccumulator = 0) // To be executed asynchronously
    } yield numberOfKeys

  def enqueueKeys(endDateTime: LocalDateTime,
                  keysCounter: Int,
                  keysAccumulator: Int): IO[Int] = ???
```

So essentially I want to fetch the number of keys to be processed from the DB, trigger the async execution of `enqueueKeys()` which will get the numberOfKeys as an input parameter, and return this number to the HTTP endpoint in order to build the response immediately after, without waiting for `enqueueKeys()` to complete its computation.

I'm wondering if it's possible to execute `enqueueKeys()` asynchronously as a batch process that should happen on another thread pool - another ContextShift. Would it be doable using [cats.effect.Async](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/async.html) or maybe using FS2?

Comment: For `IO` you can just  `_ <- enqueueKeys(endDateTime, numberOfKeys, keysAccumulator = 0).start` and it will run in background. You may also, take a look to `backgroud` if you need to handle errors or cancellation. - Also, if using **fs2** you may also look to other combinators like `concurrently` - Finally, I would recommend you to ask in the gitter channels and if you got a nice answer posted it here for future readers :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you mean using Cats Fiber? https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/fiber.html At first I tried to do that but I thought that the result of the flatMap (for) would have been stuck waiting for enqueueKeys to finish. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. A **Fiber** represents a computation that is already running. You are only waiting for the runtime system to start it, after that you can cancel it or wait for its completion, or you can just forget about it to leave it running in back ground.